# Android Studio - Switch between Activities - findViewById is null

Tags: java, android

i have a drawer layout in an base activity.
All my Activies inherit from this base activity.

i have two activities.
MainActivity
Activity2

As long as i am in MainActivity where also my WebView is, everything is working fine.

But when i am on Activity2

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

myWebView is null.

So how can i go back to MainActivity
AND THEN set and URL to myWebView when i am on Activity2?

When i try this and i am in Activity2

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        if(myWebView == null) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
//myWebView IS STILL NULL!!
```

So i hope you understand what my problem is.

The WebView is on MainActivity.
If i am on Activity2, i want to go back to MainActivity AND THEN set the url for WebView

i tried so many things like                                     onBackPressed(); or finish() ....

but nothing worked for me

thanks a lot

Comment: you want to pass the url of first activity to second activity ? Your webview is null because you didn't set any value to webview. So just pass the value by using intent and set to webview

Comment: share the layout xml of both the activities.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in Activity2, you can't get a reference to the Webview that was declared in MainActivity.  If Activity2 needs its own Webview, it has to declare the Webview in its own layout xml file which you point to when you setup your layout inflator.  If Activity2 needs to pass some information back to MainActivity, such as a URL, it would do so in an Intent before returning to MainActivity.  This would require MainActivity to have used startActivityForResult().

In MainActivity.java

```
            Intent iIntent = new Intent(thisContext, TripActivity.class);
            TripItem trip = new TripItem(0, 0, employeeID);
            iIntent.putExtra("trip", trip);

            startActivityForResult(iIntent, ACTIVITY_TRIP);

    .....

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent returnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, returnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 

    case ACTIVITY_TRIP:
        if (resultCode == android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK){  
            String url = returnedIntent.getStringExtra("my_url", false);
            myWebview.loadUrl(url);
        } 
        break;

    ...
```

In Activity2

```
                //Some click event in Action2
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                //Pass information back to MainActivity
                intent.putExtra("my_url", url); 
                //Tell MainActivity everything worked OK in Activity2
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                //End Activity2
                finish();
            }
```